# paso de variables entre funciones con JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy teniendo algunas dudas encuanto a la logica de pasar variables entre funciones, el ejemplo es el siguiente:

teniendo 3 funciones (funcionprincipal,funcionsecundaria y funcionfinal)

//funcionprincipal envia y recupera valores via ajax, manda a llamar funcionsecundaria y funcionfinal

```
$('.input').on('click',function (){
//aqui obtengo el valor del DOM que usare para el primer envio de informacion via ajax con su respectiva respuesta
var unavariable = $(this).attr("id");
})
.done(function(data){
//con el data obtenido consulto un controlador diferente via ajax nuevamente genero un QUERY EN SQL y retorno la informacion
})
.done(function(data){
//asigno la informacion de la consulta en sql en un elemento <table>, botones y demas
//TAMBIEN HAGO LA LLAMADA A funcionsecundaria
funcionsecundaria();
funcionfinal(unavariable); //AQUI ESPERO ENVIAR "unavariable" y el RETURN de funcionsecundaria(otravaciable)
//funcionfinal(unavariable,otravariable)
});

function funcionsecundaria(){
//despues de obtener los resultados deseados, funcion1 manda a llamar funcionsecundaria
//aqui hago un barrido de elementos que necesito y creo un json de sus id
//ESTA FUNCIÓN RECIBE UNA ENTRADA DE VALORES MANUAL
var otravariable=JSON.stringify(a_r_r_a_y_s);

return otravariable;
}

function funcionfinal(){
//aqui espero obtener los dos valores (unavariable y otra variable) seran enviadas a un controlador en php y ocurrira la magia
//funcionfinal(unavariable,otravariable)
//TENIENDO EN CUENTA QUE ESTA FUNCION SERA DESENCADENADA POR funcionprincipal
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar tienes que tener en cuenta el ámbito de las variables en JavaScript (lo que en inglés se denomina "scope"). JavaScript define dos ámbitos para estas, uno global y otro local.

A grandes rasgos, si una variable es declarada dentro de una función, su ámbito será dentro del bloque de esa función, y fuera de esta, la variable no existe;

```js
function ejemplo() {
  var numero = 1;
}
//La variable numero fuera de la funcion no está definida
console.log(numero);
```

Por otro lado, cuando ejecutas la funcion secundaria dentro de la funcion principal, no estás guardando el valor que te devuelve dicha funcion, que como indicas al final, luego debe recibir la funcion final. Para pasar esta variable a la función final, debes guardar antes el valor devuelto en una variable que esté contenida en el ámbito local donde pasarás por parametros el valor;

```js
$('.input').on('click',function (){

var unavariable = $(this).attr("id");
}).done(function(data){
  //codigo
})
.done(function(data){
/*Aqui no guardas el valor devuelto por funcionsecundaria, con lo que al llamar la funcionfinal 
(que debe recibir dos parametros como indicas al final de tu script) no le estas pasando 
correctamente las variables. Deberia ser algo asi;*/

var variablesecundaria = funcionsecundaria(otravariable);
//otravariable guardara el valor que retorna la funcion

funcionfinal(unavariable, variablesecundaria);
});

function funcionsecundaria(){

var otravariable=JSON.stringify(a_r_r_a_y_s);
return otravariable;
}

function funcionfinal(unavariable, otravariable){
  //codigo
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Puedes revisar algo más sobre el ámbito de `var` en la documentación de mozilla [var - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/var). Además en ECMAScript 6 se introduce otros tipo de declaraciones como son las de [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/const) y [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let)

Comment: gracias @asantana o ,  entiendo lo que cometas con respecto a guardar el valor de la función en otra variable, de hecho lo había intentado de esa manera, el problema ahí es que funcionsecundaria recibe entrada manual de valores, entonces al llamar funcionsecundaria desde funcion principal no existe algun tipo de brake por lo que la var que contiene a funcionsecundaria se pasa como null.

Comment: ¿y cuando recibe la entrada manual?, debes pasar entonces la variable que entre de forma manual a la funcionsecundaria cuando es llamada en la funcionprincipal

Comment: El flujo es el siguiente:
 1-se hace click en un checkbox y obtengo el id (funcionprincipal)
2- el id obtenido lo utlizo como parametro en una consulta sql (funcionprincipal)
3-en caso de la consulta no este vacia obtengo la tabla cuya consulta utiliza el paramtro id anterior(funcionprincipal)
4-de dicha tabla obtengo el id de N campos seleccionados MANUALMENTE (funcionsecundaria)
5-teniendo el id se la funcionprincipal y el arreglo de ids de funcion secundaria retorno a funcionprincipal para enviar enviar ambos datos a funcionfinal para alterar la informacion de la DB